# react native function is undefined inside iterator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

*This is my code*, and I am trying to call `downloadPdfFiles` this function and it's showing downloadPdfFiles undefined please look in to this and let me know

```
{
  this.state.filesLits && this.state.filesLits.map(function (files, index) {
    return (
      <li kye={Math.random()}>
        <a onClick={this.downloadPdfFiles.bind(files.originalFilesName, files.fileName, files.attachmentId)}
           style={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>
          <span>{files.originalFilesName}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: please add more relevant code, esp. content of `filesLits`

Comment: Are you really using React Native? That looks a lot like HTML to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Edit oxlx8ork2q]

this should work :

```
  downloadPdfFiles = (originalFilesName, fileName, attachmentId)=>{

    console.log(originalFilesName, fileName, attachmentId)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <block>
        {this.state.filesLits && this.state.filesLits.map((file, index)=>(
            <li key={Math.random()} >
              <a onClick={(e)=>this.downloadPdfFiles(file.originalFilesName, file.fileName, file.attachmentId)}
                style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}>
                <span>{file.originalFilesName}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
      </block>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **lexical scope** issue.
Use arrow function to fix it. It will bind to `this` having definition of `downloadPdfFiles`.

```
{this.state.filesLits && this.state.filesLits.map((files, index)=> {
        return (
            <li kye={Math.random()} >
                <a onClick={this.downloadPdfFiles.bind(files.originalFilesName, files.fileName, files.attachmentId)}
                    style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}>
                </a>
            </li>
        )
    })}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you look on the definition of `bind` you have to set an instance. If you don't want to bind it anywhere and just give parameters it should look like this:

`this.downloadPdfFiles.bind(null, files.originalFilesName, files.fileName, files.attachmentId)`

if not like this:

`this.downloadPdfFiles.bind(this, files.originalFilesName, files.fileName, files.attachmentId)`